# Do SIEM appliances perform similar tasks to non-commercial anti-malware software?

Tags: antimalware, siem

First of all, let me apologise if this is considered an ignorant question. I'm new to the concept of SIEM and have been asked by my new employer to familiarise myself with the subject.

I understand that SIEM is a security appliance for enterprise users, and that there are many different versions out there - I'm currently trying to understand the McAfee SIEM product.

My question is this, do SIEM appliances perform *similar* tasks (as well as the additional, high-end enterprise tasks on top) as done by non-commercial anti-malware software available to general consumers; e.g. detecting/stopping viruses and other threats, scanning systems for threats, etc. but on an "enterprise" level, or are they a completely different kettle of fish and are not to be confused with each other at all?

Do they share any similarities at all?

If a similar question has been asked before on this site, please do point me towards it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In the current form I consider the question as too broad since it looks like you did not have a closer look at what SIEM is yet. I actually recommend to have at least a look at the [Wikipedia entry for SIEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_information_and_event_management) which gives a good overview about what a SIEM is, what it is used for and what information it collects. Then compare this with what you know about *"non-commercial anti-malware software available to general consumers ... "*. Once you have a better understanding you can ask more specific questions.

Comment: Agreed with Steffen. It looks like you have not done any research on your topic at all, and ended up asking an impossible question to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-Virus scans files for malware signatures. It could run on an email gateway or firewall or individual machines

A HIDS runs on individual machines (usually servers) and checks for malware signatures, rootkits, and modified files, and analyzes network activity (for that machine), and log entries. Generally you want your HIDS to report to a central server

A NIDS runs on a dedicated computer or device, usually connected to a mirror port on a switch, or on a network tap. It analyzes network traffic looking for intrusion signatures

Syslog runs on individual machines and logs system and application info. Hopefully you ship these logs to a central server

A SIEM collects data from your HIDS and NIDS and syslog and *correlates* the info, looking for suspicious *interactions*

There are open-source SIEMs such as OSSIM